# Lipschitz-Constant $\sup\limits_{x\in B}||df(x)||=K<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Observe $B:=B_r(x_0)\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with $r>0$ and $x_0\in
> > \mathbb{R}^N$. Furthermore let $f: B\to \mathbb{R}^M$ be a function.
>   Show:
>
> If $f\in C^1(B, \mathbb{R}^M)$ mit $\sup\limits_{x\in
> > B}||df(x)||=K<\infty$, then  $f$ lipschitz continuous  in $B$ with
>   Lipschitz constant $K$.

**Idea:**

I know that if $f: B\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and if $x,y\in B$, the connecting line $S_{x,y}:=\{x+t(y-x) : 0\leq t \leq 1 \}$ is also in $B$ that:$$|f(y)-f(x)|\leq M||y-x||$$ with $M:=\max \limits_{\xi \in S_{x,y}}|| \text{grad} f ||$. But why is $M<\sup\limits_{x\in
B}||df(x)||=K<\infty$?

Comment: Can't you apply your result for each component $f_i$ of $f$ ?
$|f_i(y)-f_i(x)|\le \lVert \nabla f_i[x]^\intercal\ (y-x)\rVert \le \max_j \ \lVert \nabla f_j[x]^\intercal\ (y-x)\rVert$ and then relate this last term with $K$ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the generalization of the Mean Value Theorem for higher dimensions, sometimes called the Mean Value Inequality.
See [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions).

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Have you read the linked entry (specifically, the section linked, '8. Mean value theorem for vector-valued functions')? It builds up lemmas to the Mean Value Inequality and answers your question.